# Twitter Streaming API query does not recognize authentication

Tags: authentication, twitter

From my google chrome browser I enter:
   https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=canucks

I get a window "Authentication Required".  I have set up a Developer app in my twitter account.  I enter my twitter User Name and my Password, and press Log In, but it keeps giving me the same Authentication Window.  Any ideas what the problem could be?

In the Authentication Required window I see the text:

"The server https://stream.twitter.com:443 requires a username and password.  The server says: Firehose."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that authorization with header info is needed.  It is more complicated than the simple URL above.  It is best done by writing some code with the authorization header needed, along with the above URL.